# Catching Exceptions in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception

I'm working on a very simple script that utilizes a canvas with an InputField and a button.  When the player presses the button, the script checks the text of the inputfield. The problem I am having is that if nothing is entered, Unity exits with an UnassignedReferenceException.

I tried catching that exception but I must be doing something horribly wrong:

```
public class Quiz : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject quizPanel;
    public GameObject input;

    public void checkAnswer(){

        Text answer = (input.GetComponent<Text>()) as Text;

        try {
            if (answer.text == "George Washington") {
                Debug.Log("True");
            }
        }catch (UnassignedReferenceException)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Wrong answer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you assigned the input GameObject in the editor? I wouldn't think you'd need to catch the exception if you've got everything set up correctly. (e.g. does the input GameObject actually have a Text component, or should you be calling GetComponent<InputField>() instead? )

Comment: FYI, Unity only throws `UnassignedReferenceException` in the editor. In a built player that will be a `NullReferenceException` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some good reasons to believe that your `input` variable is somehow invalid. So I'll advise you to make your `try/catch` encapsulate all of your code:

```
public void checkAnswer(){
    try {
        Text answer = (input.GetComponent<Text>()) as Text;

        if (answer.text == "George Washington") {
            Debug.Log("True");
        }
    }catch (UnassignedReferenceException)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Wrong answer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, yeah you're absolutely right.  I must not actually be pointed to the right text field in the first place.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

1) I put all your code into a try-catch

2) Make sure you log your exceptions.

```
public class Quiz : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject quizPanel;
    public GameObject input;

    public void checkAnswer(){
        try {
        Text answer = (input.GetComponent<Text>()) as Text;


            if (answer.text == "George Washington") {
                Debug.Log("True");
            }
        }catch (UnassignedReferenceException ex)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Wrong answer");
            Log.Item(ex); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason to log an exception?  I assume I can later find the log and get details about the thrown exception?

Comment: @greyspace, yes that is correct. If you run your game at runtime without debugging and something happens, you can always see what the exception is thrown in the logs.

Comment: This answer is better since it picks up on the exception not being named.